# surveymonkey api authorization issue

Tags: php, api, authorization, surveymonkey

We are setting up a website, where users will fill out and submit answers to a surveymonkey survey. After the user submits his survey answers, we will access that data through an API call and generate a report for the user based on that data.

Everything works perfectly, EXCEPT every time I open a new browser and access the website, it takes me to https://api.surveymonkey.net/oauth/authorize?client_id=XXXXXX&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2FXXXXXXXXX%2Flogin_with_surveymonkey.php&response_type=code&state=1379358300-12fd31&api_key=XXXXXXXXXX (the X's cover identifying info), where I need to "Authorize user_name to use your SurveyMonkey account" ('user_name' is the SM-developer account login name). Once I input my SM account login and password, the website works perfectly and I can successfully do as many API calls as I want without any issues. However, if I close and reopen the browser window, I need to go through that tedious authorization process again.

Is there any way to permanently grant authorization to my surveymonkey account for my app, so that I don't need to go through this process every time I open a new browser window?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

How are you storing the access token for the SurveyMonkey user?

Once you have generated an access token via OAuth for a particular SurveyMonkey user, that token will work until it expires (if it has an expiry time in it) or until the user revokes access.  Only when that happens, i.e. you receive an error saying "Client revoked access grant", you should discard the old access token and reauthorize.

The access token is what you get back when you call through to /oauth/token (with the code retrieved from /oauth/authorize).

Comment: Thanks so much... it took me a while to figure this out but your comments helped greatly. I was using the login_with_surveymonkey.php code found here: http://www.phpclasses.org/discuss/package/7700/ . Basically to make it work, I needed to run the code once to find out the fields 'access_token' and 'access_token_type' for the variable $client. Then I edited the script setting those fields to what they should be, and also commented out the '$client->Process' step in the code. Then the code works smoothly... More here: http://www.phpclasses.org/discuss/package/7700/thread/100/ .